# Route all the URLs starting with a specific word to one specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am a newbie in rails and this question might sound very silly. 
I want to route all the links which start with the word 'GitRepos/' to one specific controller.

The links can be

> GitRepos/Linux/Fedora/readme.txt

or

> GitRepos/Linux/Ubuntu/config/lib/testing.md

In either of the cases I'd want my route to direct to *Markdowns#view* controller.

I have my routes as

```
    match 'GitRepos/' =>'markdowns#view'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the following to your route

```
match '/GitRepos/*path' => 'markdowns#view'
```